# particle effect does not appear in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

EDIT
OK I found this video that explains how to use it : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCLa-rgR_MA

it works with this code:

```
//in create
effect = new ParticleEffect();
FileHandle fileDir = Gdx.files.internal("data");
effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/myParticleTxtFile"), fileDir);
effect.start();

//in render
effect.draw(batch, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
batch.end();
```

---

Previous message:
I created a particle effect with the particle editor, I added the text file to the `data` folder. The particle constructor needs an atlas, so I created a new atlas with `TexturePacker` but I could not make it work.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer and mark it as solved? It could help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found this video that explains how to use it : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCLa-rgR_MA

it works with this code:

```
//in create
effect = new ParticleEffect();
FileHandle fileDir = Gdx.files.internal("data");
effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/myParticleTxtFile"), fileDir);
effect.start();

//in render
effect.draw(batch, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
batch.end();
```